# Adding columns to table depending on input number in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I have tried

```
   <div class="row"> 
<table border='2'>
 <tr>
 <th ng-repeat="o in callarr">{{o.callarr}}</th>
 </tr> 

//html table <td ng-repeat="x in makeCall() track by $index">This is column #{{$index + 1}}</td> </tr> <table>
```

I want to draw a table in angularjs with specified number of columns given in text box..Suppose the input is 6,6 columns should automaticaly drawn to table....number of rows are fixed..plz help me..

Comment: This is not coding service show us your effort?

Comment: <div class="row">
<table border='2'>
<tr>
<th ng-repeat="o in callarr">{{o.callarr}}</th>
</tr>



//html table
<td ng-repeat="x in makeCall() track by $index">This is column #{{$index + 1}}</td>
</tr>
<table>

Comment: edit the question itself and add that code ... then it can be formatted and read by all

Comment: need more details ... what will be displayed when adding / removing columns. There is no information regarding your data. Objective should be explained in more detail

Comment: there is no need to remove columns...just take input from user and build a table with that many columns

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
<element ng-repeat="x in range(numCols) track by $index">This is column #{{$index + 1}}</element>
```